# How to submit concurrent MYSQL queries (SELECT queries) at an instance?

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, perl, fork

I want to submit simultaneous MYSQL queries (only select, as i know Insert/Update are executed sequentially on the database end). 
Can this be done using a single connection and several query threads/processes?

A solution using Java threads or fork in PERL would be favourable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mysql driver does not support async requests. You should make connection pool and route requests to them by yourself. To avoid blocking, try using threads or fork() and transfer data via IPC.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using threads of course you can, and if you're just reading there's no problem. Implement your threads and in run method add the logic for your queries. If you're working with different tables, then you can create a thread for each table or for each type of query. It depends on your requirements or your needs.

Comment: I just want to test the performance of a database. So basically i want to fire the same query several time at once and calculate the time taken. However this should be done using a single connection handler. Thanks in advance.